# How can I add custom Javascript files into Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, node-modules

I'm working on my own components of Bootstrap 4 for a dashboard site.

Currently, however, I've been hitting a roadblock, whereby I need to add custom JS to be compiled with my Bootrap 4 project. However, whenever I've attempted to do an "Include" for a module it's not allowed me because i couldn't use an include outside of a module.

I assume all these modules are "NPM" modules, of which is there a way to have one locally only (That doesn't ever get uploaded to an online NPM database?

I really don't want to have to move away from Bootstrap 4 because it has the framework I want, if there are any suggestions on how I can connect TeamCity/Perforce onto Bootstrap "Easily" give me a heads up. I've been struggling with trying to get PHP/Python/P4/TeamCity to integrate fully, even if there are existing modules to do such a thing.

I could move to the Python based bootstrap systems but from my understanding they are quite slimmed down in terms of functionality, and I don't know how much work would need to be done to move them over.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving to Django in the end - Was a fairly easy move.